# how to format list and assign them separately?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a python function which returns list type data which is in this format:

```
[15, [17, 35, 34]]
```

first part is number and Second sub list is Time list in `H:M:S`
How to format and assign it as:

```
a = 15 
time = 17:35:34 ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `datetime.time` and format function :

```
>>> l=[15, [17, 35, 34]]
>>> a=l[0]
>>> d = datetime.time(*l[1])
>>> '{:%H:%M:%S}'.format(d)
'17:35:34'
```

Other example :

```
>>> l=[17,2,3]
>>> d = datetime.time(*l)
>>> '{:%H:%M:%S}'.format(d)
'17:02:03'
```

Comment: This will return invalid time string for `[15, [17, 1, 2]]` data.

Comment: @kpokhrels you are welcome. so you can also tell this to community by accepting the answer ;)

Comment: And how do i tell this as Accepted answer ? I am new here.:-)

Answer (score 2):

```
data = [15, [17, 35, 34]]
a, (h, m, s) = data
time = '%02d:%02d:%02d' % (h, m, s)
```